# Calculating difference of elements of array in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

How to subtract the first 3 row of the table

TVA Collectée -TVA Deductible-Tva deductible/immo

if the difference between them is positive, I want to put the calculated result in the box TVA à Payer and if it is negative in the box Crédit de tva

This is my html code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="styled-table" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <thead>
      <tr height="50">
        <th align="center" width="150">&nbsp;</th>
        <td align="center" width="150" *ngFor="let item of listdate">{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <th>TVA Collectée</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let c of listTvaVente">
              <label *ngIf="item === c.date">{{c.tvaCollectee | number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>TVA Déductible</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of listTvaAchat ">
              <label *ngIf="item === c.date ">{{c.tvaDeductible| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>TVA Déductible/immo</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of listTvaInv ">
              <label *ngIf="item=== c.date ">{{c.tvaDeductible| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <th>TVA à Payer</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of listApayer ">
              <label *ngIf="item=== c.date ">{{c.tvaPayer| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Crédit de TVA</th>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of date">
          <td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let c  of creditTva ">
              <label *ngIf="item=== c.date ">{{c.tvaCredit| number : '0.3-3'}}</label>
            </ng-container>
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  listdate = ['Janvier-2021', 'Février-2021', 'Mars-2021'];
  date = ['2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03'];

  listTvaVente = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaCollectee: 36000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaCollectee: 35455.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaCollectee: 45000.0
    }
  ];

  listTvaAchat = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaDeductible: 26000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaDeductible: 26000.0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      chiffreAffaireHT: 0.0,
      tvaDeductible: 32000.0
    }
  ];
  listTvaInv = [
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaDeductible: 13000.0
    }
  ];

  listApayer = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      tvaPayer: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      tvaPayer: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaPayer: 0
    }
  ];

  creditTva = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      tvaCredit: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      tvaCredit: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaCredit: 0
    }
  ];

  ReportedTva = [
    {
      date: '2020-01',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'JANUARY',
      tvaReport: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-02',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'FEBRUARY',
      tvaReport: 0
    },
    {
      date: '2020-03',
      year: 2020,
      month: 'MARCH',
      tvaReport: 0
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const length = this.listdate.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const subValue =
        this.listTvaVente[i].tvaCollectee -
        this.listTvaAchat[i].tvaDeductible -
        this.listTvaInv[i].tvaDeductible ;
        

      if (subValue >= 0) {
        this.listApayer[i].tvaPayer = subValue;
      } else {
        this.creditTva[i].tvaCredit = subValue * -1;
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i have a calculation error how could i solve i?

Link to the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-playground-s4hphq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Nourhene, you has a "crazy" group of variables -see that some arrays has less elements than anothers, you should create a "more comprensible object" with all the data. Some like

```
data=[] //declare an array where you store the data

//iterate over one array
this.listdate.forEach((x,i)=>{
   const yearmonth=this.date[i].split("-")
   const year=+yearmonth[0], //the "+" convert to numeric
   const month=+yearmonth[1], //the "+" convert to numeric
   data[i]={
      dateTxt:x,
      date:this.date[i],
      year:year,
      month:month,
      tvaVente:(
         this.listTvaVente.find(t=>t.year==year && t.month==month) ||
         {tvaCollectee:0}
         ).tvaCollectee, //(*)
      tvaAchat:(
         this.listTvaAchat.find(t=>t.year==year && t.month==month) ||
         {tvaDeductible:0}
         ).tvaDeductible,//(*)
      tvaInv:(
         this.listTvaInv.find(t=>t.year==year && t.month==month) ||
         {tvaDeductible:0}
         ).tvaDeductible//(*)
   }
})

//(*)see that I make
//     (list.find(...) || {property:0}).property
//so, if not found return an object with the property, and get the property
```

know is easer create the table and the operations using "data"